# Importing files for tests written on Mocha/Chai/TypeScript both in browser and Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mocha.js, chai

I have tests written on TypeScript using Mocha and Chai. I want it to work both from browser and NodeJS.

Here is my test case snippet:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/mocha/mocha.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../typings/chai/chai.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../typings/node/node.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../src/scripts/mymodule/mymodule.ts"/>


module mymodule.DecryptSequenceBuilder.Tests {


    var expect = chai.expect;
    var should = chai.should;
    var assert = chai.assert;

    describe('DecryptSequenceBuilder', function() {

        describe('Builder tests', function() {

            it('gets all files together with one cert', function() {
                var files = [
                    {
                        filename: 'file1.xml',
                        encrypted: true,
                        encryptedOn: ['cert1', 'cert2', 'cert3'],
                        compressed: false,
                        contentType: "xml"
                    },
                    {
                        filename: 'file2.xml',
                        encrypted: true,
                        encryptedOn: ['cert4', 'cert5', 'cert3'],
                        compressed: false,
                        contentType: "xml"
                    }
                ];
                var steps = mymodule.DecryptSequenceBuilder.build(files, ['cert1', 'cert2', 'cert3', 'cert4', 'cert5'], []);
                var trueSteps = [
                    {
                        'certSerial': 'cert3',
                        'provider': 'toolbox',
                        'files': [files[0], files[1]]
                    }
                ];
                assert(steps.length === trueSteps.length);
            });
            ................
```

And here is my test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/mocha.css" />
  <style>
    #fixture {
      position: absolute;
      top: -9999;
      left: -9999;
    }
  </style>  
  <script src="node_modules/chai/chai.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
  <script> mocha.setup('bdd');</script>  
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      mocha.run();
    };
  </script>

  <script src="../src/scripts/mymodule/mymodule.js"></script>
  <script src="test/testcase.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="mocha"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

So I include all builded JS files in HTML and there are no problems in browser. But how to include my libraries in TypeScript? 
When I was writing tests on pure JS there was this code in the beginning of test case:

```
if (typeof require !== 'undefined') {
    chai = require('chai');
    mymodule = require('./../../src/scripts/mymodule/mymodule.js');
    mymodule = mymodule.mymodule;
}
```

But now it doesn't work in TypeScript because TypeScript think I've already included module "mymodule" and I try to initialize variable "mymodule".
How can I include files for NodeJS properly?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I include files for NodeJS properly?

Use *file based modules everywhere* and compile with `--module commonjs`

More http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/external-modules.html

This will work out of the box for node.js. For frontend you can just use something like webpack to get a single `.js` file.

Comment: I can't recompile TS for browser and for NodeJS. I need TS code which will be compiled to JS via VS2013 and this compiled JS should work both in browser and node.